# Correct way to pushViewController in this case?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, pushviewcontroller

I have a custom UITabBarController. On it I have added 3 view controllers adding a navigationController to each one first. It looks like this

· customTabBarController.m viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FirstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstController];

    SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondController];

    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, nil];

    [self addLeftButtonImage];
    [self addRightButtonImage];
    self.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Now, when I am on a view controller and I want to pushViewController, how do I have to call it?